# xsd: restrict values based on key

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

Is it possible in xsd, to demand the following restriction.

Given this xml:

```
...
<map>
    <key-value key="foo">some value</namespace>
</map>
....
<examples>
    <example property="foo:bar" />
</examples>
....
```

The `map` keys are unique. What I want is to restrict the value of the attribute `property` so that any string before the ":" will match a map key.
I tried doing this using `xs:keyref` but found that it uses a subset of XPath that does not include the use of functions such as `substring-before` and `substring-after` (see [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch09_02.htm), section 9.2.5).

The xsd looks something like:

```
<xs:element name="map" type="mapType">
     <xs:key name="mapKey">
         <xs:selector xpath="key-value"/>
         <xs:field xpath="@key"/>
     </xs:key>
</xs:element>
....
<xs:element name="example">
     <xs:attribute name="property" type="propertyAttributeType" use="required">
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:element>
.....
<xs:simpleType name="propertyAttributeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    </xs:restriction>
    <!-- what do i do here? -->
</xs:simpleType>
```

Is it at all possible, or will I have to enforce this behaviour in code?

Comment: You can do it with an XML Schema 1.1 assertion but not with a 1.0 key/keyref.

Comment: @IanRoberts Care to expand?

Comment: On the element that is the container for map and examples, add the condition `<xs:assert test="every $e in .//example/@property satisfies some $k in .//key-value/@key satisfies substring-before($e, ':') eq $k"/>`